# How to get full profile access for LinkedIn API?

Tags: laravel, api, web-services, linkedin-api

I'm building a job seeker platform and I want the user to extract their profile data from LinkedIn for this purpose I'm using LinkedIn API. By default, LinkedIn provides us with basic profile access to (firstName,lastName,userProfilePicture) fields. But I need the skills and education information of my job seeker as well. I have applied for LinkedIn in Partner Program a week ago but they have not responded yet. Please guide me through the process that how can I get access to LinkedIn full profile.
My question here is that:

- Am I using the right approach to access full profile.
- Is there any other way I can get the full profile of my job seekers